# How to tell whether imaplib2 idle response resulted from timeout

Tags: python, timeout, imap, python-idle, imaplib

I'm using [imaplib2](http://www.janeelix.com/piers/python/) ([docs](http://www.janeelix.com/piers/python/imaplib.html)) to interact with an IMAP server.

I'm using the idle command, with a timeout and a callback.

The problem is, I don't see any way of telling if the callback was triggered by the timeout being reached, or if there was a change on the server that I need to check out.

I just get `('OK', ['IDLE terminated (Success)'])` every time.

Here's the debug output for both cases:

**Timedout:**

```
15:43.94 MainThread server IDLE started, timeout in 5.00 secs
15:48.94 imap.gmail.com handler server IDLE timedout
15:48.94 imap.gmail.com handler server IDLE finished
15:48.94 imap.gmail.com writer > DONE\r\n
15:49.17 imap.gmail.com reader < DDDM6 OK IDLE terminated (Success)\r\n
15:49.17 imap.gmail.com handler _request_pop(DDDM6, ('OK', ['IDLE terminated (Success)']))
```

**Something happened:**

```
18:41.34 MainThread server IDLE started, timeout in 50.00 secs
19:01.35 imap.gmail.com reader < * 1 EXISTS\r\n
19:01.37 imap.gmail.com handler server IDLE finished
19:01.37 imap.gmail.com writer > DONE\r\n
19:01.59 imap.gmail.com reader < BFCN6 OK IDLE terminated (Success)\r\n
19:01.59 imap.gmail.com handler _request_pop(BFCN6, ('OK', ['IDLE terminated (Success)']))
```

What am I missing?

Does the functionality just not exist in imaplib2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piers Lauder (author of imaplib2) just answered this question on the imaplib2-devel mailing list. He said:

> I think the way to test if an IDLE has timed out is to  execute:
>
> ```
> instance.response('IDLE')
> ```
>
> which will return:
>
> ```
> ('IDLE', ['TIMEOUT'])
> ```
>
> if the reason that the idle returned as a timeout, rather than
>   something else (such as `('IDLE', [None])`).
>
> I agree that this should be documented, so I'll fix the imaplib2.html
>   document

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manually check for new messages each time you get this response. You can store the UIDs of messages in a list and compare new UIDs with it upon each callback. This way you can easily tell if there are new messages or a timeout.